# Resetting GIT local to remote version

Tags: git, ssh, git-commit, git-reset

I'm trying to reset my Git because I'm having all kinds of problems. It would not allow me to push several large files to my remote and I don't know how to delete them from the commit. I don't recall even committing the files.

my remote is: pmp_staging

```
kjlin@LAPTOP-BU6U18C6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/postmyproject (master)<br>
$ git push pmp_staging master<br>
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/kjlin/.ssh/id_rsa':<br>
Counting objects: 7215, done.<br>
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.<br>
Compressing objects: 100% (7006/7006), done.<br>
Writing objects: 100% (7215/7215), 44.69 MiB | 1.01 MiB/s, done.<br>
Total 7215 (delta 1112), reused 0 (delta 0)<br>
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1112/1112), done.<br>
remote:   git.wpengine.com: validating<br>
remote:   - info: detected push to staging application ...<br>
remote:   - info: validating files in 9f1931e ...<br>
remote:   - info: found application servers ...<br>
remote:  failed...<br>
remote:   system/large file types detected:<br>
remote:   ------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/preamble.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/redis-object-cache.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/s3-uploads.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/util.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/admin-footer.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/admin/advanced.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/admin/debug-db.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/admin/notice-sticky.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/admin/notice.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/general/powered-by.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/modal.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/staging-modal.php<br>
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/views/wpe-migration-preview-<br>template.php
remote: wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/wpe_wpdb.php<br>
remote:   ------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:   please remove these files from your source, re-commit, and push...
To git.wpengine.com:staging/postmyproject2.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to'git@git.wpengine.com:staging/postmyproject2.git'<br>
```

I couldn't figure out how to remove these files from the original commit. I tried moving the head back to the origin but can't seem to get rid of them. Instead, I'd like to start fresh. I just want my Git remote to match my local so I can start practicing pushes and commits. Everything I look for on stack overflow doesn't seem to work.

```
kjlin@LAPTOP-BU6U18C6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/postmyproject (master)<br>
$ git fetch pmp_staging<br>
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/kjlin/.ssh/id_rsa':<br>
<br>
kjlin@LAPTOP-BU6U18C6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/postmyproject (master)
$ git reset --hard master/master<br>
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.<br>
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'<br>
<br>
kjlin@LAPTOP-BU6U18C6 MINGW64 /c/wamp64/www/postmyproject (master)<br>
$ git reset --hard pmp_staging/master<br>
fatal: ambiguous argument 'pmp_staging/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.<br>
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Clone it again?

Comment: You can try "git reflog" to see previous HEAD position and then use reset --hard to that position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used`rm -rf .git` to delete my entire git repository.

I had to restart and followed the directions in [WPengine's GIT Page](https://wpengine.com/git/)

I had initially setup an SSH for WPengine.com using  [Git Hub's](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) help. This allowed me to get my SSH key and input it into my install on WPengine.com.

After that I had to follow the directions carefully. I downloaded a zipped install and pasted into my local WAMP folder. Logged into GIT Bash and setup the SSH under my /c/wamp64/www/my_install/ folder.

I had to download and setup the .gitignore file that allows for Wordpress Core changes because we've actually edited some of those files for object oriented programming.

I then simply followed WPengine's protocol:

```
$ cd ~/wordpress/my_wp_install_name
$ git init .
$ git add . --all
$ git commit -m "initial commit..."
```

I must have intially forgot to 'add . --all'.

Setup my install to remote to my Staging:

```
$ cd /c/wamp64/www/my_install
$ git remote add staging git@git.wpengine.com:staging/my_install.git
```

I then deployed to my remote:

```
 $ git push staging master
```

So far GIT is working until I screw it up next time.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Linden It's really help me +1

Answer (score 0):

From what you're telling `git reset --hard pmp_staging/master` should work, unless there's no master branch on pmp_staging which would be weird.

Run `git branch -a` to double check that `pmp_staging/master` exists.

Answer (score 0):

For my case there **were** large `*.mp4` files in my theme folder, this happened to me after migrating to wpengine and this was the first commit I pushed using their **Git Push** method. I only deleted them as they said in CLI, re-commited and pushed again without even using `-f` to force it.